# Fur on the inside of object

Tags: eevee-render-engine, hair

I"m using the fur feature of Blender 3.5. When I add fur to my model by doing *Add > Curve > Fur*, the fur grows on the inside of my model. How can I fix this? Or is it a problem with my mesh?

[image]

Comment: Maybe try to flip your normals (alt N)?

Comment: Also, check the *Surface Deform* modifier. Is it at the bottom of the stack? Does it show an error message? Is the model properly UV mapped? There must be no overlapping UV islands and no mirror.